# Is there any alternative to putclientproperty in Android,in Java I used putclientproperty

Tags: java, android

I had created some edittext and buttons dynamically in Android. In java, I used putclientproperty for jtextfield and jbutton. Is there any other alternative in Android? I had found setid which must be in int. I need to set it in a string.

Answer (score 0):

[Use `setTag()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)) and [`getTag()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag()) to attach an arbitrary object to a `View`.